Is it possible to connect USB 3.0 over a SATA data connection?
This may sound strange, so I'll provide some context. A long time ago, I made a little device that I really liked, but the technology was too immature at the time. It consisted of an ARM single board computer which had USB OTG support. Using Linux USB Gadget, I was able to provide USB Mass Storage devices to a PC that was backed by a file stored on the ARM. This would enable me to do some fancy stuff transparent to the PC, like cloning disks, snapshots, etc. It was a fun project, but it only had USB 2.0, the IO was lousy, it didn't have much RAM and overall, the technology just wasn't there. But now things have changed and I've just bought an ARM device that has eight CPU cores, 16GB RAM, USB OTG 3.1 gen 1 and 4 lanes of PCIe 3.0 for m.2 storage. So I've decided to recreate this project, hoping that this time, I could possibly get some decent performance.
However, I just had a wild idea. Because mechanically, I will be able to fit this SBC with two m.2 cards into an enclosure that's mechanically compatible with 2.5" devices and even have space for heat sinks on both sides, to cool both the SOC and the NVMe. So I'm thinking that I could use existing SATA/SAS hot swap chassis as a kind of cluster in a box, ready with power supply, cooling and caddies. I could of course modify that chassis to provide a USB connector instead of a SATA data connector, but it would be even better if I could simply do the USB signalling over the SATA connector, connecting it to an internal USB hub rather than a SATA controller. The SATA power connector provides both the 5v needed for USB and the 12v needed for the SBC,so this is beginning to sound kind of nice to me.
But is this plausible? SATA data has seven pins while USB 3 has 9, but if I'm getting the power from the SATA power connector, I'm down to 7. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible, but I've learned that just because I don't know something, doesn't mean everything is possible. :) So I would like some feedback on this idea, which at this point is purely hypothetical. Don't worry about your advice causing fires. :)
If this even works, would it be dangerous if this was accidentally connected to a real SATA port or would it just not do anything?

Possible? Perhaps. I don't believe that this is something you can get with a simple adapter though, so you're probably stuck at manually modifying a connector or cable. However, USB3 will likely not run at anywhere close to full speed over any SATA cable due to the differences in the standards for the cables for each of these, and you may end up with a lot of data errors.

Yes, I'll need special cables anyway, so that's not an issue. But I'm wondering about things like whether it matters that I'm not getting power from the usb, like if that's necessary in order for the host to be aware of the device.
